# Why We Use RequireJS on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

Please tell me why we use requirejs and require-configjs files and purpose of these two files on magento 2.Complete Details if Possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html):

> To address the problem of slow page load, we exclude JavaScript from the page headers and we added the ability to use the RequireJS library.
>
> RequireJS improves the perceived page load time because it allows JavaScript to load in the background; in particular, because it enables asynchronous JavaScript loading.

It is also used to track/inject dependencies to make managing Javascript easier. If you've worked on Magento 1 you'll remember the huuuuuge JS files that were difficult to maintain.